# Protecting AngelScript source code

Tags: c++, include, angelscript

A few months ago I thought about adding AngelScript to my engine, which I will definitely do.

Now one thing I am worried about is protecting users source code. Indeed if I use AngelScript it's to make my game engine moddable (well actually the games I will make with it moddable), but even if I am an open source enthusiast, final commercial products must be protected, so my scripts source must be protected. Also I know some modders prefer their code to be protected.

The thing is, how do I do that? Encryption idioms? AngelScript bytecode? Knowing that one of the constraint is that all produced code is reusable, even if we cannot see the implementations.

Encryption is my first idea so if that's the thing you advice me to use, is there some better type of encryption to use (private/public key, encryption algortihm...)?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: something like [this](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/doc_adv_precompile.html) ?

Comment: Yes it is the byte code I a talking about, but I see nothing in this page that explicitly says that "appending" code to it, or making this bytecode includable is possible. Well actually the way it works, it must have a trace of every names and so on ! Thing is, it is mostly to protect the developers (long story short, I intend to make the engine open source in the far future) source script code. And I don't yet know if the better solution is the inclusion of bytecode, which now seems quite complicated, or the encryption of said source code (in which case I'd have to change the title).

Comment: @MatthiasB Well yes I will entirely adapt the question, thanks for the answer and the link by the way.